# footer menu doesn't slide up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a top menu for website with 2 features:

1. fixed nav bar in scroll bottom
2. slide toggle navbar

this is the demo : [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xaruf/2/edit)

but I have 2 problems :

When the page is in top and menu is in default the slide toggle works well

but after scrolling the page to the bottom and clicking the arrow under navbar the slide toggle doesn't work

menu contains 2 div :

menu:

```
<div id="menu" class="top-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll">home page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#events" class="scroll">m</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">dfsdfs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and div for arrow key and line under navbar:

```
<div id="menu-footer">
  <div style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #CD1D27;padding:7px 0;"></div>
  <div id="open-close-toggle" style="background:url(http://up.tractorfc.com/images/48714086549751927852.png) no-repeat;height:32px;background-position:center;"></div>
</div>
```

2nd problem is in menu-footer

I think there are better ways for replacing this code to having arrow key and show red line when menu is slide up

and I use this script for slide menu bar :

```
<script>
  $("#open-close-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: In <div id="menu-footer">, there is only a part of link (<li><a href="#home"). This might be causing problems.

Comment: @smclark89 : no i edit that part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That HTML was busting it. Here's a working version that toggles a class on the footer to get it to sit at the top of the page. http://jsbin.com/widaq/2/edit